# Performance/flexibility as in instance a class or extend it

Tags: java, performance

I am using 2 libraries and I need a class from one of the libraries to have functionality from the other. My first try was to take the source of library A and make the class extend the class from library B. This works kinda fine except alot of fixing etc which don't make the code all that stable etc and updating one of the libraries became a hell.

like this:

```
abstract class classA extends classB{
}
```

Now I also thought about doing something like this:

```
abstract class newClass extends classB{
    private classA A = new classA();

    public void exampleMethod(){
        A.exampleMethod();
    }
}
```

Is the second option bad performance-wise? and if it is, how bad?

Comment: What about moving the `exampleMethod()` to `classB`? To solve this problem, it would be easier to have a more concrete example. And by the way, check the naming of your classes and fields agains the Java Coding Conventions

Comment: Then I would be altering a class from the library again, something I wanted to get rid of. And in my personal case it would mean a hell of combining two pretty huge libraries that depend on many superclass's that would be needed to combined too to preserve all functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension through delegation form (mixin) is desirable for a variety of reasons here, but the most pertinent is that you are (likely) extending 3rd party library classes in a non-normative manner.

But this is all guessing since we have *no idea* what libraries you are talking about.  For example, it may be that it is a poorly written library where `classA` (using your example) really is not supposed to be extended but the author neglected to spec `final class classA`, etc.  If that were the case, then clearly you do not want to extend that class (even if you can).

All that said, given the fact that you (a) only need shared functionality, (b) do not require polymorphic semantics, the delegated form makes perfect sense.

Advice regarding performance anxiety: benchmark it.

And don't neglect final -- JIT is your friend (be nice to it and feed it):

```
final private classA A = new classA();
```

Comment: While I agree that it's a good idea to make `A` final, I don't see how that impacts the JIT.

Comment: That final should decisively inform the JIT that the delegated call stack (references) will never change and can be collapsed without any heuristics.  (I believe you are correct once it has warmed up though.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, Erich Gamma in the 1st chapter of the GoF book states: "Favor object composition over class inheritance". See: http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples4.html .

Comment: No idea who that is but his argumentation seems valid enough to make a prototype using object composition

Comment: Or in other words: avoid premature optimization.